# fopen issues with <form> and current file

Tags: php

I am able to take a name from a form a user has submitted and create a file using fopen. What I need to do is whenever a user hits that submit button I want to take their name `$_POST['name']` and use it to rename a current file I have in the same directory. The files name is comment.PHP.  and it has a script for entering comments. So ....when the user hits submit I need to to create a file with `$_POST['name']` . So it should look like
Jamescommet.PHP and if another person submites their name it will make a fill called
tomcomment.php. and I need the files to keep the current script in it.
So what should I change?

```
$filename = $_POST['name']_comment.PHP;
```

Thanks for the help, the only problem that persists. Is that none of the code from comment.PHP was included into the file created?

---

Thanks for the help, the only problem that persists. Is that none of the code from comment.PHP was included into the file created?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enlcose some of this in quotes (or single quotes):

```
$filename = $_POST['name'] . "_comment.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP the '.'  is the concatenation operator.  This means that it combines two strings into one.  The quotes are used to encapsulate a string.

So to combine a variable like `$_POST['name']`
to a string such as `_comment.php`

we do the following:
`$_POST['name'] . "_comment.php"`

This will combine the variable and the string like you expected.

#### References that may help.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php